# Can a definition within an array item's schema be referenced?

Tags: jsonschema

Is it possible for a `"definitions"` section within a schema that is within the `"items"` section of an array schema to be referenced via a `"$ref"` ?

For example, in the JSON below (assuming it's valid), how would `"a_def"` be referenced elsewhere in the document (i.e. what path would be used) ?:

```
...
"an_array": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": [{
            "definitions": {
                "a_def": { ... }
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Please re-phrase your question so that it will be clear what example input should be valid and what would be invalid as per your schema.

Comment: @erosb my concern right now isn't with actual sample instances, just if such a cross reference can be made within a JSON schema. From what I've read on JSON pointer notation my impression is that this might be possible: `.../an_array/items/0/definitions/a_def` ?

Comment: yes, that should be possible, just give it a go